# Вроде бы простой код jquery, но почему не работает?

Tags: jquery

Код должен выводить ошибку если значение в поле для ввода не соответствует нужному. Ошибка срабатывает только с именем (при вводе менее 3 символов). В остальных случаях (email, subject и message) код не работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
$title = "Обратная связь";
require_once "blocks/head.php"
?>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready (function () {
$("#done").click (function () {
$("#messageShow").hide ();
var name = $("#name").val ();
var email = $("#Email").val ();
var subject = $("#subject").val ();
var message = $("#message").val ();
var fail = "";
if (name.length < 3) {
fail = "Имя не меньше 3 символов";
 } else if (email.split ('@').length - 1 == 0 || email.split ('.').length - 
1 == 0) {
fail = "Вы ввели некорректный E-mail";
 } else if (subject.length < 5) {
fail = "Тема сообщения меньше 5 символов";
 } else if (message.length < 20) {
fail = "Сообщение не менее 20 символов";
 }
if (fail != "") {
 $('#messageShow').html (fail + "<div class='clear'><br></div>");
 $('#messageShow').show ();
 return false;
}

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Шапка-->
<?php require_once "blocks/header.php"?>

<!--Статьи-->
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="leftCol">
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" id="name" name="name"><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email"><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Тема" id="subject" name="subject"><br/>
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"> 
</textarea><br />
<div id ="messageShow"></div>
<input type="button" name="done" id="done" value="Отправить">
</div>

<!--Реклама в правой части-->
<?php require_once "blocks/rightCol.php"?>
<!--Футер-->
</div>
<?php require_once "blocks/footer.php"?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var email = $("#email").val(); // не $("#Email").val();
```

*Совет дня:*

Держите открытой консоль браузера и обращайте внимание на ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо. Как это я даже не заметил.

Comment: @ЗахарКудрявцев На здоровье. "Галочка" - слева от ответа. Успехов!